# Rendering Google Drive video files on my website using Google API key

Tags: wordpress, google-api, google-drive-api

I am managing a Wordpress website that uses the Ultimate Video Player plugin in order to render video files that are stored in my Google Drive account.

Plugin details: https://www.webdesign-flash.ro/p/uvp/

In order to render the Google Drive video files, this plugin needs the video file sources to be created using the following format:

https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/[file_id]?alt=media&key=[api_key]&v=[.mp4/.mp3/etc]

Therefore I have created a Google API key that I’m using to build my video source links.

So here are my questions:

1. Are there any limitations as to how many times a video can be visualised on my website (how many hits it gets) using the GoogleAPI key created?
2. Is there a download quota that can be exceeded by rendering these video files on my website as described above?

Thank you very much for your assistance.

Comment: I think you should be using Youtube for this Google drive is a file storage system it is not designed to be used in this manner your defiantly going to be hitting quota issues with this probably because google doesnt want you using it like this.

Comment: I'm with DalmTo here. Also: Hosting is getting cheaper and cheaper, you could just put the video files on your WP host and deliver them from there. And I'm not sure if Google Drive is really supposed to be used like this. They could block/delete your account if they find this behaviour malicious or against their TOS.

Comment: Thank you so much for your replies. My website is about cinematography and I have several movies streaming online (they are legal). The problem is that I’m getting closer to the limit of my hosting plan’s available storage space so I’m looking for alternative ways of hosting my video files. I wasn’t able to find online exactly how many hits a video can get on my website before exceeding the Google API download quota. For example, if I had 2000 hits per 24 hours per API key, I could create several API keys for several videos. Any additional information on this matter is greatly appreciated.